# Is it possible to activate a program by powering on/plugging in a specific USB device?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, script, automation, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to react on attaching (or switching on) a specific USB device on the PC's USB hub, in order to automatically execute a Powershell script (or run an executable or a batch script)?

Specifically, I have a stationary barcode reader, providing input to a program expecting the read barcodes. The barcode reader is not used often (it's keeping track of inventory items), hence is off most of the time.

The goal is to simply activate the associated program, so that scanning can be done without further ado.

**Edit:** The device seems not to produce relevant events when switching on or off, see in the comments for details. Thanks LPChip.

In case it's relevant, as per the device manager's driver tab, the device in question **identifies as HID\VID_0C2E&PID_0200\7&3445e1e3&0&0000**. It's not present when switched off.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to automatically start an application when a USB storage device is plugged in?

Comment: I think Task Scheduler vs Eventlog monitoring can do this, but I'm not sure how it reacts and if it can filter out a specific device.

Comment: @Ramhound, no, not a storage device. As I said, a barcode scanner. Which, for practical purposes, can be regarded as a keyboard delivering some characters and an Enterkey.

Comment: @LPChip, in the Task Scheduler's `Create a task`, `Trigger`, `New` dialog the only sensible trigger seems to be `On an event`, right? Then `userdefined` as there is no suiting predefined trigger. In there are some sources named `USB-...`, suggesting the use of one of these. The `Device Manager` lists a total of 6 `USB Input Devices`, which jumps to 7 on powering on the barcode reader. On inspecting their locations, I can find my reader at location `Port_#0001.Hub_#0004`. And now I'm lost. What can I do with this information?

Comment: First, you need to find anything in the eventlog that goes about the reader, then see if you can work with that.

Comment: @LPChip, thanks for your suggestions so far. The imo most promising EventLog node would have been Microsoft/Windows/DriverFramework-UserMode/Operational, right? Well, it is completely empty.

Comment: The best thing you can do is download a program called: NirSoft FullEventLog which will show you the entire eventlog in one overview. Then plug in the device, sort by time/date and find the event that way.

Comment: @LPChip, I did, thanks. On switching on/off the barcode reader, only events from the channel: Microsoft-Windows-Audio/PlaybackManager (Provider: Microsoft-Windows-Audio) are listed. The exactly same is true when switching on/off other non-memory devices attached to the same USB hub. I am pretty sure, that they reflect the system sounds "USB device attached" and "detached", which are audible indeed.

Comment: Yeah, quite likely. That means there's no way you can automate things using build-in windows functions.

Comment: @LPChip, thanks for your advice. One more thing, before I consider programming an app polling the system's hardware: on powering on, a new HID Keyboard appears in DeviceManager > PCName > Keyboards (it identifies as HID\VID_0C2E&PID_0200\7&3445e1e3&0&0000). This fact can not be exploited?

Comment: What do you mean by exploited? This is the ID of the hardware. In fact, googling that string will give you reference for that specific hardware.